# Tomcat 6 not deploying webapp folders OS X

Tags: osx-lion, tomcat6

I have used MacPorts to install tomcat 6 for use with `launchctl`.
`launchctl start org.apache.tomcat` provides the following result in Catalina.*date*.out:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)` and so on

Lo and behold, there is no folder called Catalina in conf.

I don't know if this is responsible for the applications not being deployed or not, but I felt that since it's a severe issue it should be noted.

Then comes `SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory manager
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)`

and for each of the folders in the webapps folder, I get

`The scratchDir you specified: /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost/examples is unusable.`

I have been googling this for some time now, but I have not yet stumbled across an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with Tomcat from Macports and permissions.
My end solution was to install and configure tomcat manually.

Comment: It would be super if you document and post the steps you took to solve this issue, so others may benefit as well.